# Rebind Single row

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .NET 4 WinForm application. I have bound a DataGrid to a collection of objects via a BindingSource.  I then modify one of the objects.  The grid is smart enough to recognise this once I click the grid, and thus shows the modified value, but I want to force it to rebind/refresh the row that is bound to the modified object without further user action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call [ResetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetitem.aspx) on the BindingSource with the index of the specified item, assuming that the BindingSource is configured to raise change events.